# SSL Certificate for proxy pass?

Tags: ssl, proxy

Let's say a user opens `https://ssl-site.example/link/index.php`
I configured my server with `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` in the Apache configuration (in `conf.d` area):

```
ProxyPass "/link" "https://other-site.example/link"
ProxyPassReverse "/link" "https://other-site.example/link"
```

So if I understand correctly, now the user sees `https://ssl-site.example/link/index.php` URL in the browser, but actually the content comes from `https://other-site.example/link/index.php`

`ssl-site.example` has a valid SSL certificate.

Does `other-site.example` also need a valid SSL certificate for the user to see a valid SSL connection looking at `https://ssl-site.example/link/index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario the TLS connection from the browser is only to `ssl-site.example`. Thus, the browser only needs to trust the certificate from `ssl-site.example`. The browser does not even know that `other-site.example` is somehow involved. The server itself must trust the certificate from `other-site.example` in order to forward request and get the response.

Comment: ok thanks. other-site.example has an SSL certificate that runs out soon. I'm not sure if this will lead to an error if the server ssl-site.example tries to acess other-site.example through an https connection? How can I test this? Can I just rename the ssl.key folder in the apache configuration of other-site.example and see if it still works?

Comment: @stackoverflow_asker: the certificate for `other-site.example` is only checked by Apache. You can try to change the clock at this system to simulate expiration. Renaming the key will not work since without a key SSL will not even be able to do the handshake which is necessary to check the certificate.

Comment: ok thanks Steffen. So I change the clock of other-site.example? If this is possible can't everybody chagne the clock to keep their certificates valid?

Comment: @stackoverflow_asker: The expiration of the certificate is checked by the client.  The client when accessing `other-site.example.com` is nginx and only nginx. If you want to check what happens if the certificate expires change the clock on the system where nginx is running. If you want to make sure that `other-site.example` is still accessible from nginx after the current certificate expired please renew the certificate instead of fiddling with clocks.